# Mode aggregation doesn't work in pandas (Must produce aggregated value)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When running this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], group=["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"]))
df.groupby(["group"]).agg({
    "x": [pd.Series.mode, "sum"]
})
```

This error is returned:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documents/Workspace/gx_ds_analytics/default_env/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    258             try:
--> 259                 return self._python_agg_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
    260             except (ValueError, KeyError):

~/Documents/Workspace/gx_ds_analytics/default_env/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in _python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1172                 # if this function is invalid for this dtype, we will ignore it.
-> 1173                 result, counts = self.grouper.agg_series(obj, f)
   1174             except TypeError:

~/Documents/Workspace/gx_ds_analytics/default_env/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in agg_series(self, obj, func)
    712                 raise
--> 713         return self._aggregate_series_pure_python(obj, func)
    714 

~/Documents/Workspace/gx_ds_analytics/default_env/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in _aggregate_series_pure_python(self, obj, func)
    753                 # We only do this validation on the first iteration
--> 754                 libreduction.check_result_array(res, 0)
    755                 initialized = True

pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.check_result_array()

pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.check_result_array()
...
pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.check_result_array()

pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.check_result_array()

ValueError: Must produce aggregated value
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the mode is returning multiple values for group "a". Changing one of the values, this works because each mode is unique:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3], group=["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"]))
df.groupby(["group"]).agg({
    "x": [pd.Series.mode, "sum"]
})
```

To use groupby which returns multiple mode values, you need to parse the modes returned. For example, select the first mode from the sorted list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], group=["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"]))
df.groupby(["group"]).agg({
    "x": [lambda s: pd.Series.mode(s).iloc[0], "sum"]
})
```

Or list all modes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], group=["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"]))
df.groupby(["group"]).agg({
    "x": [lambda s: list(pd.Series.mode(s)), "sum"]
})
```